# Socket.io broadcast to not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code:

```
var room = "1";
var chat = io.connect("localhost:3700/");
    self.chat = chat;
    chat.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.emit("room", room);
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            self.receiveMessage(data);
        });
    });

 chat.broadcast.to(room).emit('send',"HEllo");
```

receiveMessage:

```
receiveMessage: function(data){

        var $elem = $("#chat1");
        var $content = $elem.find(".messageText");
        if(data.message) {
            messages.push(data);
            var html = '';
            for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                html += '<b>' + (messages[i].username ? messages[i].username : 'Server') + ': </b>';
                html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
            }
            $content.html(html);
        } else {
            console.log("There is a problem:", data);
        }
    }
```

The line `chat.broadcast.to(room).emit('send',"HEllo");` gives me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'to' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure but I think you can send a broadcast only on connection.

You can try this:

```
var room = "1";
var chat = io.connect("localhost:3700/");
    self.chat = chat;
    chat.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.emit("room", room);
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            self.receiveMessage(data);
        });


        chat.broadcast.to(room).emit('send',"HEllo");
    });
```

Of course you can also send the broadcast in a separate handler, i.e.:

```
var room = "1";
var chat = io.connect("localhost:3700/");
    self.chat = chat;
    chat.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.emit("room", room);
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            self.receiveMessage(data);
        });

        socket.on('foo event', function(data) {
            chat.broadcast.to(room).emit('send',"HEllo");
        }
    });
```

Comment: how do I then call the `foo event` programatically? I'm new to socket so a little confused ;)

Comment: And in fact - the `connection` function is never triggered

Comment: @rickyduck socket.emit('foo event',data); will call the 'foo-event'.